# How to retrieve data from xml files in particular conditions

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I want to create a desktop application in java which runs on every system but when I create it with MySQL as database then there is a problem with it because it’s not necessary that MySQL installed on every system. So because of this, I am using xml files to store data. But now some issues encountered -

1. Is there any alternative to store data in primary-foreign key relationship?
   If yes then how?
2. How to retrieve data on different conditions and from different xml files (like sql queries operate on two or more tables in MySQL).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770948/primary-and-foreign-keys-in-xml-schema

Comment: Im expecting what you want is actually [embedded database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison)